# EDITTED: Find all values of $a$ and $b$ so that $ax^n+b\cos\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)$ is Cauchy.

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, continuity, cauchy-sequences

For each $n\in\mathbb{N}$ let

$$f_n(x)=ax^n+b\cos\left(\frac{x}{n}\right), \text{ } x\in[0,1].$$

Find all values of $a$ and $b$ for which $(f_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence in $C[0,1]$, the space of continuous functions on $[0,1]$ equipped with the metric

$$d(f,g)=\sup_{x\in[0,1]}|f(x)-g(x)|.$$

**EDITTED:**

My working:

For any given $\epsilon>0$ we need to find an integer $N$ such that for all $m,n\geq N\implies d(f_m,g_n)<\epsilon$.

So we have
$d(f_m,g_n)=\sup_{x\in[0,1]}|f_m(x)-g_n(x)|$
$=\sup_{x\in[0,1]}|a(x^n-x^m)+b(\cos\left(\frac{x}{m}\right)-\cos\left(\frac{x}{n}\right))|$

I get stuck if I used the definition of Cauchy.

As mentioned by Martín-Blas Pérez Pinilla, the space $C[0,1]$ is complete, hence Cauchy implies convergent and conversely?

My doubt is, since the metric is the supremum metric, is the convergence that we are talking about the uniform convergence?

But we don't know the limit apriori yet, then how can we show that it is convergent?

Can anybody please give some helps on how to proceed?

Thanks in advance! Really appreciate it!

Comment: Note that $\cos (x/n)$ converges uniformly (why?) and thus you need only to deal with $x^n$.

Comment: Yes, the convergence in the supremum metric is the uniform convergence.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: your space is complete, so Cauchy $\implies$ convergent. Now, what happens with the *pointwise* limit?

Comment: Isn't it supposed to be Cauchy $\iff$ convergent? So do we have to show that $f_n$ is a pointwise convergent sequence? Thanks you.

Comment: But if we need to show that it is convergent, do we need to know the limit a priori?

Comment: @user71346, (1) *uniformly* Cauchy $\iff$ *uniformly* convergent, (2) you can prove (uniform) convergence *without* knowing the limit, (3) if a sequence converges uniformly the limit will be the pointwise limit.

Comment: So if that's the case, we know that $x^n$ does not converge uniformly on $x\in[0,1]$, so the value of $a$ must be 0?

Comment: @user71346, yes.